# How to save data in external storage instead of internal storage? Android | Java

Tags: android

In this code, I am saving data(audios, videos, images) to internal storage. What changes should I make to it to store data in external storage?
Please help.

```
final File f = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("received"),
                          "SmartDataTransfer");

                File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                if (!dirs.exists())
                    dirs.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();

                InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();

                FileOutputStream Out = new FileOutputStream(f);

                copyFile(inputstream, Out);
```

Comment: What do you mean by external storage?

Comment: Here is an overview about the required permissions:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage